# working with two mac computers and github

Tags: git, github

I have working code on a mac with github repository. I backed up everything to Time Machine. I am planning to exchange the old mac and dont need it any longer.
I moved all the content from Time machine to new mac, rebuilt the code. To set up git on the new mac, I generated a new key and added the key to github. I have made changes to code on the new mac and is therefore more recent then the one on the github repository. What are the steps to push the new code from new mac to github?

Comment: The steps are: `git push`. Was there a particular problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: Please see my updated comments below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To set up git on the new mac, I generated a new key and added the key to github

You did the right thing; SSH keys should be per-machine. Having added the public part of that key to GitHub, you are ready to rock and roll. Just follow the instructions for setting up SSH (note the stuff about the credential helper):

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

The very first time you push to GitHub, do it at the command line, so that you can respond to the query about trusting GitHub.

Comment: From the working directory of new mac, I did git add *; git commit -m "comments"; so far works good. Then git push -u origin master. It asks for passphrase and I provide the passphrase that I set up while generating/saving the key with ed25519. It doesn't take it. After couple of tries, says: fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. I go to github and made sure that the new mac key has been added. How to fix it?

Comment: I tried ssh -T git@github.com. Says Enter passphrase for key '/Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa. since I generated key using ed25519., shouldn't it be asking for Enter passphrase for key /Users/myname/.ssh/id_ed25519. Because I see the private key when I cat /Users/myname/.ssh/id_ed25519. So how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds to me like you didn't follow all of the directions at https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: I know what the mistake was. The ~/.ssh/config file had  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519. Since it was executing sequentially it was getting hung on rsa and asking me the passphrase for rsa whereas I had generated the key using ed25519. I delete the rsa line from the file and retried. It works fine now.

Comment: Yup, that’s what I mean about following directions. You did not do what it said to do at https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent